# Java windows commands not executing?

Tags: java

When I run this program itdisplays the following text instead of the dir dump why? This is what it displays.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7600]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
```

It should also display the dir out put but it does now why?

The code

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;


public class ExecuteWindowsCommandThread implements Runnable {

    public ExecuteWindowsCommandThread(String command) {
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            final Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd c/ dir");
            //p.waitFor();
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String line = null;

            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            System.out.println("Done2");

        }

        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Done");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `c/` instead use `/c` so, Change:

```
final Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd c/ dir");
```

to:

```
final Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c dir");
```

and it will work.